# No puedo llenar mi BD

Tags: php, mysql

tengo un formulario que debe registrar los postgrados con los datos necesario, pero los postgrados se separan en nacionalaes e internacionales. Actualmente no logro que los datos se intraduzcan a la BD y no lanza ningún tipo de error y eso es lo que me frustra bastante. Segun el diseño del formulario, si se marca la opcion de internacional, muestra nuevos inputs que se deben llenar para su posterior envio. Implemente el codigo que consiste en un IF que ejecuta un INSERT a la BD en el caso que sea internacional, pero no estoy muy seguro de su fiabilidad. En general, el 1er IF verifica si se preciono el boton de envio y ejecuta el llenado de la tabla BD llamada postgrado. El 2do IF es para el caso de que el postgrado se internacional. Agradeciria mucho su ayuda.

```
<?php  
    include 'conexion.php';

    $codigo = $_POST['text_codigo_postgrado'];
    $tema = $_POST['select_tema'];
    $fechaInicio = $_POST['text_fecha_Inicio'];
    $fechaFinal = $_POST['text_fecha_Final'];
    $profesor = $_POST['select_profesor'];
    $impartido = $_POST['rbtnImpartido_Centro'];
    $cantHoras = $_POST['num_cant_horas'];
    $cantAlumnosNac = $_POST['num_cant_alum'];
    $cantAlumnosInt = $_POST['num_cant_alum_ext'];
    $Pais = $_POST['select_paises'];
    $tipo = $_POST['rbtnTipo'];

    

    if (isset($_POST['btn_postgrado'])) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $tb_postgrados (impartidoCentro, cantAlumnos, cantHoras, fechaInicio, fechaFin, codigo, idTipoPostgrado,    idTema, idProfesor) VALUES ('$impartido', '$cantAlumnosNac', '$cantHoras', '$fechaInicio', '$fechaFinal', '$codigo', '$tipo', '$tema', '$profesor')";
        
        $INSERT_SQL = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
        $id = mysql_insert_id();

        extract($_REQUEST);     // Captura los datos por GET o POST
        if ($tipo == "Internacional") {
            $q = "INSERT INTO $tb_postgradosInt VALUES ('$id', '$cantAlumnosInt', '$Pais')";

            $INSERT_Q = mysqli_query($conexion, $q);
        } 
        
        include 'cerrar_conexion.php';
    } 



?>
```

Este es el formulario con el que estoy trabajando.

```
<form class="form-signin reset" id="form_int" name="form_int">
                    
                        <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 form-group">
                          <label for="text_codigo_postgrado">Código del Postgrado</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="text_codigo_postgrado" id="text_codigo_postgrado" placeholder="00" maxlength="2">
                          <div class="invalid-tooltip" id="alerta_codigo">Código Incorrecto</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12 form-group">
                          <label for="select_tema">Tema</label>
                          <select class="custom-select form-control " name="select_tema" id="select_tema">
                            <option value="0"> ...Seleccionar...
                            </option>
                            //Más opciones
                          </select>
                          <div class="invalid-tooltip" id="alerta_tema">El tems es incorrecto</div>
                        </div>
                      </div><br>
                          
                          <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 form-group">
                          <label for="text_fecha_Inicio">Fecha de Inicio</label>
                          <input type="date" class="form-control" id="text_fecha_Inicio" name="text_fecha_Inicio"> 
                          <div class="invalid-tooltip" id="alerta_inicio">Escoja la fecha de inicio</div>
                          <div class="invalid-tooltip" id="alerta_fecha_incorrecta">Las fechas son incorrectas</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 form-group">
                          <label for="text_fecha_Final">Fecha de Cierre</label>
                          <input type="date" class="form-control" id="text_fecha_Final" name="text_fecha_Final">
                          <div class="invalid-tooltip" id="alerta_cierre">Escoja la fecha se cierre</div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="text_nombre">Profresor Principal</label>
                                <select class="custom-select form-control " name="select_profesor" id="select_profesor">
                          <option value="0"> ...Seleccionar...
                          </option>
 //** Más opciones **
                        </select>
                        <div class="invalid-tooltip" id="alerta_profesor">Nombre Incorrecto</div>
                            </div><br>
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                          <h6>Tipo de Postgrado</h6>
                          <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input class="custom-control-input" name="rbtnTipo" type="radio" id="radio_centro" value="Nacional">
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="radio_centro">Nacional</label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input class="custom-control-input" name="rbtnTipo" type="radio" id="radio_ext" value="Internacional">
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="radio_ext">Internacional</label>
                            <div class="invalid-tooltip" id="alerta_opcion_tipo">Seleccione una opción</div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                          <h6>¿Fue impartido en el centro?</h6>
                          <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input class="custom-control-input" name="rbtnImpartido_Centro" type="radio" id="SI" value="Nacional">
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="SI">SI</label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input class="custom-control-input" name="rbtnImpartido_Centro" type="radio" id="NO" value="Internacional">
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="NO">NO</label>
                            <div class="invalid-tooltip" id="alerta_opcion_imp">Seleccione una opción</div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      
                      
                                  <br>

                              <div class="form-row">
                          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 form-group">
                            <label for="num_cant_horas">Cantidad de horas</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="num_cant_horas" name="num_cant_horas" placeholder="0">
                            <div class="invalid-tooltip" id="alerta_horas">introduzca las horas</div> 
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 form-group">
                            <label for="num_cant_alum">Alumnos nacionales</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="num_cant_alum" name="num_cant_alum" placeholder="0"> 
                            <div class="invalid-tooltip" id="alerta_alumnos">Introduzca los alumnos</div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 form-group oculto" id="alum_ext">
                            <label for="num_cant_alum_ext">Alumnos internacionales</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="num_cant_alum_ext" name="num_cant_alum_ext" placeholder="0"> 
                            <div class="invalid-tooltip" id="alerta_alumnos_ext">Introduzca los alumnos</div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 form-group oculto" id="div_pais">
                            <label for="select_paises">País</label>
                            <select class="custom-select form-control " name="select_paises" id="select_paises">
                              <option value="0"> ...Seleccionar...
                              </option>
\\ **más opciones**
                            </select>
                            <div class="invalid-tooltip" id="alerta_pais">Introduzca el país</div> 
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success align-bottom" id="btn_postgrado" name="btn_postgrado">Aceptar</button>  
                  </form>
```

Comment: *pero no estoy seguro de su fiabilidad*. Pues eso es parte de tu tarea como programador, escribir código fiable, seguro y totalmente controlado. Y para hacerlo hay que preveer todos los posibles fallos y controlarlos. Es decir, tienes que recuperar el resultado de cada consulta (`mysqli_query()` devuelve `false` cuando hay fallos), verificar ese estado y mostrar un mensaje adecuado. Siempre insisto en lo mismo, cuando programas tienes que ser pesimista, no optimista. Tienes que pensar que TODO puede salir mal y que tu tarea como programador es responder cuando eso ocurre.

Answer (score 0):

No soy experto en php. Pero no veo que realices commits después de realizar los inserts.
A no ser que tu código de cerrar conexión realice un commit dentro. O tengas definida una conexión con la base de datos con autocommit. Es posible que realices el insert y vaya todo bien pero como no realizas el commit los datos no se persisten.

Si puedes debugar el código php y llegar hasta la línea donde realizas:

```
include 'cerrar_conexion.php';
```

Sin que salte ningún error seguramente lo que te falte es realizar un commit.

En Java es más sencillo, porque si utilizas frameworks como Spring anotas los métodos que requieren transacción con una anotación y ya se encarga por ti de realizar los commits si todo ha ido bien o los rollback si se ha producido una excepción.

Comment: Disculpa, pero que significa commit? Yo tengo otro formulario que también inserta en la BD y trabaja bien. El que m está dando problema es este. Así que conexión.php y cerrar_conexion.php hacen su trabajo. Pienso que el problema está en este formulario. Voy hacer un if para ver el resultado de cada consulta a ver qué error da.

Comment: Disculpa, pero que es un commit?? Realicé otro formulario que inserta los datos a la BD sin problema alguno. Así que asumo que ```conexion.php``` y ```cerrar_conexion.php``` están haciendo bien su trabajo. Parece que el error está en el código PHP de este formulario, pero al no lanzar errores no sé dónde está el problema. Voy a tomar la idea A. Cedano y voy a capturar el resultado de las consultas. De todas formas, si detectan algún error, se los agradecería

Comment: Los gestores de bases de datos relacionales para hacer modificaciones (insert, update, delete) suelen  trabajar por transacciones. Puedes hacer que un conjunto de instrucciones de modificación se comporten como una unidad para no dejar cosas a medias. O se realizan todas las operaciones o si falla una se deshacen aquellas que se hubieran ejecutado. Para indicar que das por bueno el bloque de operaciones de una transacción existe la iinstruccion: COMMIT;

Comment: Por ejemplo detrás  de tu instrucción  insert deberías  ejecutar COMMIT. Desconozco cómo  se hace en php. Pero en SQL sería: INSERT .....; COMMIT;. Podrías añadir el COMMIT;  justo detrás  del punto y coma de tu insertar para descartar lo que te comento de los commits. Aunque si otro ejemplo te funcionó  igual el error está  en el php.

Comment: Soy nuevo en este mundo de PHP y MySQL. Estoy trabajando x descarte. Tengo k ver bien el código PHP de este formulario. Lo he estado modificando y aún así, no lanza error. De todas formas le agradecería que vieran mi código PHP a ver si ven algo k yo no logro ver. Miles de ojos ven más que 2

Comment: He puesto un echo al principio y al final de código PHP y si me lo muestra, pero cuando pongo ese echo dentro del if, no hace nada. Eso quiere decir que el error está en el if. Lo he revisado, pero aún así no logro ver el fallo.

Comment: @CasinerO ¿estás poniendo `method="POST"` en la etiqueta `FORM'? En el extracto HTML que has puesto no aparece y los formularios por defecto se envían con GET.

Comment: Revisé el HTML, pq veía el código PHP sin problema y ahí m di cuenta de eso ‍♂️. No sé cómo se me pudo pasar x alto. Gracias x darte cuenta de tal garrafada. Ese era el error.